# Epic fantasy art scenery

Tags: fantasy, art

I'm gonna be running a video-game-esque fantasy campaigns for some friends soon and one of my major world inspirations is the Final Fantasy series, in all its iterations.

For some unique locations I'm looking for galleries of epic fantasy artwork, stuff like floating mountains, ancient castles, magical forests, etc. Where can I find this online? Google and deviantart haven't proven fruitful, although I've found a few good leads on tubmlr.

Bonus points for floating islands/mountains ;)

Any suggestions?

TL;DR where do you get your fantasy scenery pr0n?

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2849/where-can-i-get-fantasy-public-domain-art

Comment: Also: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9023/where-can-i-find-artwork-for-my-games/9026#9026

Answer (score 2):

Boris Vallejo: http://vallejo.ural.net/

Larry Elmore: http://larryelmore.com/

Answer (score 2):

Top one would be [ArtStation](https://www.artstation.com/). It is a professional site, so you will find high quality work there.

[CGtalk](http://forums.cgsociety.org/) is one of the best place to look for high quality artwork.  [Photo.net](http://photo.net/), especially its digital modification section, is a good place to look for things as well.

Finally, google image search is good.  Terms like "concept art" + game/book/character/setting will give you a trove of information.  Same with "fan art" + game/book/character/setting.